# make wget refer to a local copy without redundantly downloading files

Tags: wget

I want to archive a message board,I do that by using wget with the parameters: `--page-requisites`, `--span-hosts`, `--convert-links` and `--no-clobber`.

The problem is that using `--convert-links` disables `--no-clobber`. for every thread page, wget re-downloads site skins, scripts and icons(For the purpose of keeping them updated).

Is there a way to prevent wget from downloading files that already exist locally, referring links to files to their local copies and only downloading files that aren't already in the filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you include the switch `-N` it will force `wget` to make use of timestamps.

```
   -N
   --timestamping
       Turn on time-stamping.
```

With this switch, `wget` will only download files that it does not already have locally.

#### Example

Download where file `robots.txt` doesn't already exist locally.

```
$ wget -N http://google.com/robots.txt
--2014-06-15 21:18:16--  http://google.com/robots.txt
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 173.194.41.9, 173.194.41.14, 173.194.41.0, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|173.194.41.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/robots.txt [following]
--2014-06-15 21:18:17--  http://www.google.com/robots.txt
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 173.194.46.83, 173.194.46.84, 173.194.46.80, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|173.194.46.83|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘robots.txt’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                 ] 7,608       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-06-15 21:18:17 (359 MB/s) - ‘robots.txt’ saved [7608]
```

Trying it a second time with the file `robots.txt` locally:

```
$ wget -N http://google.com/robots.txt
--2014-06-15 21:18:19--  http://google.com/robots.txt
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 173.194.41.8, 173.194.41.9, 173.194.41.14, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|173.194.41.8|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/robots.txt [following]
--2014-06-15 21:18:19--  http://www.google.com/robots.txt
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 173.194.46.82, 173.194.46.83, 173.194.46.84, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|173.194.46.82|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Server file no newer than local file ‘robots.txt’ -- not retrieving.
```

Notice that the 2nd time, `wget` did not retrieve the file again.

Comment: It works. Thank you, really. I'd like to note that I've tried that timestamping option before, mirroring said messageboard and wget claimed there's no information in the header, so I just ommited it. I didn't find anything about it in the documentation either. Thanks again.